# Use symbols from **bartel-chess-fonts** in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, overleaf, chess, installing-fonts

I want to use a few symbols from the [**bartel-chess-fonts**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bartel-chess-fonts) font in two projects in Overleaf (one is pdfLaTeX, other is XeLaTex). I downloaded the contents, which are all **.mf** or **.tfm** files, and added these to a bartel-chess-fonts folder in Overleaf.

At this point I am however stuck on how I can load and use some of these symbols within the text of the document.

I looked to several questions in the Stack, however most are either not for Overleaf or only deal with **.ttf** files.

I appreciate your help!!

Comment: there is no need to install anything manually. The fonts are in texlive and so available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fonts only with low-level commands, or through the diagram package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chess-problem-diagrams. There is no nfss-support for LaTeX.

So normally something like `\font\chessfont=pkelch12 {\chessfont \char99}` is needed, you can find out the char number by looking at the font table below. I had to tweak an internal command as the fonts have a bit curious design size.

The fonts are bitmaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}

\font\chessfont=pkelch12 {\chessfont \char99} 

\makeatletter

% to get around the curious design size in the fonts:
\renewcommand*{\f@tstartfont}{%
  \@tempdima=\f@size pt
  \font\f@ttestfont=\f@tfontname\space at 100pt\relax %force size ...
  \f@ttestfont \f@tsetbaselineskip
  \ifdim\fontdimen6\f@ttestfont<10pt\relax
    \rightskip=0pt plus 20pt\relax
  \else
    \rightskip=0pt plus 2em\relax
  \fi
  \spaceskip=\fontdimen2\f@ttestfont % 
  \xspaceskip=\fontdimen2\f@ttestfont
  \advance\xspaceskip by\fontdimen7\f@ttestfont
}




\fonttable{pkelch12}
%\fonttable{fselch12}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I use the diagram package for the symbols (I used that one before but changed to skak). Small follow-up question. For the diagram package I copied the diagram.dtx, and diagram.ins into my project folder, however if I copy them to a dedicated packages folder and use \RequirePackage{packages/diagram} in my .cls file, I get the error that LaTeX cannot find the diagram.sty file. However, if I copy it to the main directory there is no problem. Any idea why this is the case and how I can fix it, of even better create an diagram.sty file myself using the .dtx and .ins file?

Comment: diagram is part of texlive too. I hadn't to install anything to use it, and it worked on overleaf too. But be aware that diagram loads pstricks, so it isn't meant for pdflatex (but probably won't break).

Comment: Thanks! When I started using it in Overleaf I got an error if I did not have the files in the directory, but most likely I made an error at that time, and since then always used to copy the dtx/ins files to any project.